# no such table: api_user

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I used `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` before, but now I need to switch to `AbstractUser`. How can I transfer the data from the previous auth_user table to AbstractUser? I followed the [code from here](https://github.com/scalablescripts/django-auth).

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True} # Don't return password
        }

    def create(self, validated_data): # Hash password
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

When I login to admin pages I get :

> no such talbe: api_user

I want to use `AbstractUser` instead without deleting the auth_user table.

Comment: "No api_user table", I guess your `models.py` file is in an `api/` django app, and the most obvious explanation is that you didn't make (`./manage.py makemigrations`) nor run (`./manage.py migrate`) the migrations required for your new model to exist in the database.

Comment: I did the following steps
1. Delete api/migrations/0001_initial.py
2. Download db.sqlite3 from server
3. Executed makemigrations and migrate --fake commands
4. Login to admin page, I encountered the no such table error
db.sqlite3 does not have an api_user table, I want the data in the auth_user table can be migrated to the api_user table.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps :

- In settings.py set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'`.
- Delete "migrations" folder.
- Delete "db.sqlite3" file.
- Run `python manage.py makemigrations your_appname`.
- Run `python manage.py migrate`.
- Run `python manage.py createsuperuser`.

Comment: I know this approach, but how can I transfer the data from the "auth_user" table to the "api_user" table?